# Spoofing IP address with PHP (no response from the server required)

Tags: php

Is there any way (something with raw packets manipulation, perhaps?) to "connect" with server using spoofed IP? I don't care about the response (which will never hit the sender).

It's purely theoretical question.

Comment: if your aim is doing a non-blocking request, then you can use curl for that.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a way to do this with PHP - to falsify the sender's IP address, you'd need access to lower levels of the protocol than PHP is able to provide.

I would usually post some helpful links, but it doesn't feel right in this case, as I can't think of many legitimate uses of IP spoofing. However, all you need to do this can be found using a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Tor Project : Vidalia 
https://www.torproject.org/projects/vidalia.html.en

They got an API which allows you to change IP(Proxies in this case) from PHP.
I had done this a couple of years ago.

Comment: Yeah, but this is a different thing, isn't it? Anonymous proxies != IP spoofing (which is faking a *specific* IP one doesn't own)